# Posterior distribution of a $\text{Gamma}(\alpha,\beta)$ random variable given a Gamma prior for $\beta$

Tags: distributions, bayesian, posterior, gamma-distribution, conjugate-prior

Let $Y$ be a $\text{Gamma}(\alpha,\beta)$ random variable with known shape parameter $\alpha$ and unknown scale parameter $\beta$. Suppose we assign a $\Gamma(\alpha_0,\beta_0)$ prior to $\beta$. I am trying to show that the posterior distribution $\pi(\beta|\alpha_0,\beta_0)$ is again a Gamma random variable. I am confused because I got stuck when using the shape-scale parameterization for the Gamma distribution, but when I use the shape-rate distribution I was able to solve it. Here's my work:

Using the rule $\text{Posterior} \propto \text{Likelihood} \times \text{Prior}$, we have
\begin{align*}
     f(\beta|\alpha_0,\beta_0) &\propto \frac{y^{\alpha - 1} e^{-y/\beta}}{\Gamma(\alpha) \beta^{\alpha}} \times \frac{\beta^{\alpha_0 - 1} e^{-\beta/\beta_0}}{\Gamma(\alpha_0) \beta_0^{\alpha_0}}   \\[5pt]
      &\propto  \beta^{\alpha_0 - \alpha -1}  e^{-y/\beta - \beta/\beta_0}
\end{align*}
But this does not look like a Gamma random variable to me; the problem is that the $-y/\beta - \beta/\beta_0$ term contains $\beta$ in the denominator of the first fraction and the numerator of the second, so I don't see how this can be put into the form $-(\text{constant}) \beta$. Did I do something wrong? Then I attempted the same calculation using the shape-rate parameterization of the Gamma distribution:
\begin{align*}
     f(y|r,v) = \frac{y^{r-1} e^{-vy} v^r}{\Gamma(r)}. 
\end{align*}

If $Y \sim \text{Gamma}(r,v)$ (with $r$ known, $v$ unknown) and $v \sim \text{Gamma}(r_0,v_0)$, then we have
\begin{align*}
   f(v|r_0,v_0) &\propto \frac{y^{r-1} e^{-vy} v^r}{\Gamma(r)} \times \frac{v^{r_0-1} e^{-v_0 v} v_0^{r_0}}{\Gamma(r_0)} \\[5pt]
    &\propto v^{r + r_0 - 1} e^{-(y + v_0)v},
\end{align*}
and from this we see that the posterior distribution is $\Gamma(r + r_0, y + v_0)$.

So my question is: Why does it work for the shape-rate parameterization, but not the shape-scale parameterization? Since the parameterizations are equivalent, I would expect that both should work...

Comment: The conjugate prior is different, that's all.  The distribution of $\beta$ is not the same as that of $1/\beta$.

Comment: @jbowman: Hmm, are you saying that the Gamma family is *not* the conjugate prior for Gamma when using the scale parameterization, but *is* conjugate when using the rate parameterization?

Comment: Well, yes, because the Inverse Gamma distributions and Gamma distributions are different.

Comment: The density$$f(\beta)\propto\beta^\omega\exp\{-a\beta-b\beta^{-1}\}$$is attached with a generalised inverse Gaussian distribution.

Comment: @jbowman After thinking about it some more, your point makes a lot of sense. I was under the false impression that two distributions with different but "equivalent" parameterizations should have the same properties w/respect to conjugacy, but now I see that's not the case.